# Promql query not working "cpu_usage_value or memory_usage_value"

Tags: time-series, promql, victoriametrics

according to prometheus doc :

vector1 or vector2 results in a vector that contains all original elements (label sets + values) of vector1 and additionally all elements of vector2 which do not have matching label sets in vector1

but the above query only returns cpu_usage_value

promql beginner, pardon if understood the doc wrong

Answer (score 0):

The `or` operator doesn't take into account metric names when searching for time series on the left side of `or`  with labelsets, which are missing in time series on the right side of `or`. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators).

There are the following solutions:

1. To explicitly mention `__name__` label (aka metric name) in the list of labels, which should be taken into account when matching series by their labelsets: `foo or on(__name__) bar` would return series with both `foo` and `bar` names.
2. To enumerate the needed metric names in [series selector regexp](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors): `{__name__=~"foo|bar"}` returns series with both `foo` and `bar` names.
3. To use [union](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#union) function from MetricsQL: `union(foo, bar)` returns series with `foo` and `bar` names. Note that this solution works only in VictoriaMetrics (Prometheus-like system I work on). It doesn't work in Prometheus :(